# Simplest way to Load a dropdown from a Javascript array and Set Selected value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a simple Javascript Array like this:

```
var directionArray = [{ id: 'N', text: 'North' },
    { id: 'S', text: 'South' },
{ id: 'E', text: 'East' },
{ id: 'W', text: 'West' }];
```

I have a select element like this:

```
<select data-ng-model="bbInventory.DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL"
                name="travelDirection"
                id="travelDirection"
                class="form-control" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

The goal is to firstly load the options from the array and then select a value once data is available.

I am drawing a blank, any input will be much appreciated

Comment: "using angularjs" in the title, [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] tags in the question. Which is it?

Comment: The dropdown can be loaded using pure javascript or jquery. The Selected Option has to be set via Angular. So, all three...

Comment: @Jesse angular is javascript, hard to fault that one

Comment: use `ng-options` to populate the `<select>`.

Comment: look at the examples in the angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: @charlietfl - Angular is to Javascript, as Laravel is to PHP. I know Javascript, I do not know Angular. There is a difference

Comment: @Jesse then ignore the question...that's pretty simple.

Comment: I would have if it did not have the [tag:javascript] tag

Comment: @Jesse Well that concept conflicts with some of the discussions in meta that suggest all questions should have a  language tag

Comment: @charlietfl - Can you link me so I can add to that discussion?

Comment: @Jesse http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308768/1175966

Comment: @charlietfl, Jesse, you are both correct, I probably shouldnt have put Javascript as it implies pure javascript. However a language tag is necessary and Angular is not a language. I apologize to both of you for the confusion.

Comment: @w2olves no, tagging as javascript is fine. Much of what needs solving in angular is done using vanilla or modified javascript methods. Angular is javascript. Anyone can ignore questions that are tagged with unfamiliar frameworks or libraries on top of the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple setup would be:

```
$scope.directionArray = [{ id: 'N', text: 'North' },
      { id: 'S', text: 'South' },
      { id: 'E', text: 'East' },
      { id: 'W', text: 'West' }];
```

And in the html:

```
<select data-ng-model="bbInventory.DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL"
        ng-options="item.id as item.text for item in directionArray"
        name="travelDirection"
        id="travelDirection"
        class="form-control" style="width: 100%"></select>
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4UQKe0gFr6FT1A4DQ1PY).

Comment: Thank you so much. I can load json array using the same set up right ?

Comment: Sure, it's all just objects :)

Answer (score 1):

use [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive

```
<select ng-model="bbInventory.DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL" ng-options="option.text for option in directionArray track by option.id"></select>
```

then to select an option use

```
$scope.bbInventory.DIRECTION_OF_TRAVEL = $scope.directionArray[whatyouwantindex];
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected Fridjon's answer as the accepted one simply because of the Plunker and he was a few seconds faster. I believe either of your's or his answer would be helpful to me as well as others who are looking for a similar solution. Thanks again